# jqgrid footervalue not correct if rows is empty

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid (ver 4.6.0.0), I show a grant total on footer of a amount column. If user insert a new row or delete a row, it should recalculate the total amount, and show it on footer. It works fine until the grid is empty(no any rows), I mean if user delete the last row on grid, the code still calculate the correct amount ( 0 ), but the footer still show the total amount it was, not 0.
Here is my code:

```
protected void Jqgrid1_DataRequested(object sender, JQGridDataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet _ds = (DataSet)Session["myApplicationForm"];
    DataTable dt1 = _ds.Tables[1] as DataTable;
    CalcVoucherAmt(dt1);
}

private void CalcVoucherAmt(DataTable _dt)
{

    decimal amtSum = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in _dt.Rows)
    {
        amtSum += obj2decimal(dr["DETAIL_AMT"]);
    }
    Jqgrid1.Columns.FromDataField("DETAIL_AMT").FooterValue = amtSum.ToString();
}

protected void Jqgrid1_RowAdding(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridRowAddEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet _ds = (DataSet)Session["myApplicationForm"];
    DataTable dt1 = _ds.Tables[1] as DataTable;
    dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns["DATA_SEQ"] };
    DataRow row = dt1.NewRow();

    row["UNIQ_KEY"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    row["DETAIL_AMT"] = amt; //user input 

    dt1.Rows.InsertAt(row, dt1.Rows.Count);
    Session["myApplicationForm"] = _ds;

    Jqgrid1.DataSource = dt1;
    Jqgrid1.DataBind();
}

protected void Jqgrid1_RowEditing(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridRowEditEventArgs e)
{

    DataSet _ds = (DataSet)Session["myApplicationForm"];
    DataTable dt1=_ds.Tables[1] as DataTable;
    dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns["DATA_SEQ"] };
    DataRow rowEdited = dt1.Rows.Find(e.RowKey);

    rowEdited["DETAIL_AMT"] = amt; //user input

    Session["myApplicationForm"] = _ds;
    Jqgrid1.DataSource = dt1;
    Jqgrid1.DataBind();
}

protected void Jqgrid1_RowDeleting(object sender, JQGridRowDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet _ds = (DataSet)Session["myApplicationForm"];
    DataTable dt1 = _ds.Tables[1] as DataTable;
    dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns["DATA_SEQ"] };  
    DataRow rowToDelete = dt1.Rows.Find(e.RowKey);

    if (rowToDelete != null)
        dt1.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);

}
```

and in aspx, the code is

```
    <cc1:JQGrid ID="Jqgrid1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" AutoWidth="true" PagerSettings-PageSizeOptions="[]" 
        OnRowAdding="Jqgrid1_RowAdding"  
        OnRowEditing="Jqgrid1_RowEditing" 
        OnDataRequested="Jqgrid1_DataRequested" 
        OnRowDeleting="Jqgrid1_RowDeleting">
    </cc1:JQGrid>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why you decide that jqGrid "should recalculate the total amount" automatically? If you insert a row using or delete a row you can specify callback which will be called at the end of Add/Delete operation. Inside of the callback you can use `getCol` to recalculate the total amount and to use `footerData` to set new value in the footer.

Alternatively you can trigger `reloadGrid` which will sort new data correctly, recalculate the total amount and to place it on the footer row. Both ways will work.

The code which you posted seems to have mo relation to jqGrid. It don't show which editing mode and how you use to Add/Delete rows. So I can't give you more detailed implementation tips.

Comment: I post the Add/Delete code on the bottom of the original code. And you can notice that I use the asp.net webform, so the reloadGrid it not workable here. Hope you can give me some advice.

Comment: @brandon: You used `jqgrid` tag of your question. jqGrid is **pure JavaScript** solution. If you use some ASP.NET WebForm then you generate some wrappers directly of indirectly. You should open the source of HTML page and see JavaScript code which you generated. If you want to speak with other using the same language you should use JavaScript terminology. `var grid = $("#<%= Jqgrid1.ClientID %>");` will get you jQuery wrapper of the grid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/aspnet/_2s90nukak.htm)) and `grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);` will do reload.

Comment: I am using the jqGrid for asp.net , it's a webform control, a commercial version. [www.trirand.net](http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/webforms/jqgrid). May be the problem I post is a bug ?

Comment: here is the sample code from [trirand](http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/webforms/jqgrid/)